# Replace single group via RegEx in all matches

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a text containing HTML-Elements, where hyperlinks contain not URLs but IDs to the item the hyperlink should open. Now i'm trying to get all those IDs and replace them with new IDs. The scenario is, that all ID's have changed and i have a dictionary with "oldId -> newID" and need to replace that in the text.

This input

```
Some text some text <a href = "##1234"> stuff stuff stuff <a href="##9999"> xxxx
```

With this Dictionary mapping

```
1234 -> 100025
9999 -> 100026
```

Should generate this output

```
Some text some text <a href = "##100025"> stuff stuff stuff <a href="##100026"> xxxx
```

So far i have this:

```
var textContent = "...";

var regex = new Regex(@"<\s*a\s+href\s*=\s*""##(?<RefId>\d+)""\s*\\?\s*>");
var matches = regex.Matches(textContent);

foreach (var match in matches.Cast<Match>())
{
    var id = -1;
    if (Int32.TryParse(match.Groups["RefId"].Value, out id))
    {
        int newId;
        // idDictionary contains the mapping from old id to new id
        if (idDictionary.TryGetValue(id, out newId))
        {
          // Now replace the id of the current match with the new id
        }
    }
}`
```

How do i replace the IDs now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't parse HTML with regular expressions.

But if you must, if you're trying to perform a replacement, *use the [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx) method*.

```
var updatedContent =  regex.Replace(textContent, match =>
    {
        var id = -1;
        if (Int32.TryParse(match.Groups["RefId"].Value, out id))
        {
            int newId;
            // idDictionary contains the mapping from old id to new id
            if (idDictionary.TryGetValue(id, out newId))
            {
                // Now replace the id of the current match with the new id
                return newId.ToString();
            }
        }

        // No change
        return match.Value;
    });
```

Edit: As you've pointed out, this replaces the *entire match*. Whoops.

Firstly, change your regular expression so the thing you'll be replacing *is* the entire match:

```
@"(?<=<\s*a\s+href\s*=\s*""##)(?<RefId>\d+)(?=""\s*\\?\s*>)"
```

This matches just a string of digits, but ensures it has the HTML tag before and after it.

It should now do what you want, but for tidiness you can replace `(?<RefId>\d+)` with just `\d+` (as you don't need the group any more) and `match.Groups["RefId"].Value` with just `match.Value`.

Comment: It's a text editor that returns HTML-Elements for formatting. But it could be pure text, so i cannot use XML/HTML Parsers.

Comment: @AlexanderMills Fair enough, just as long as you can rely on the `<a>` tags matching your pattern.

Comment: Is it possible to only replace the ID (the matched group), and leave the "a href" untouched? This solution replaces the hyperlink with the ID only, and manually putting a "a href" around the return result again seems fishy to me

Comment: @AlexanderMills Yup, my mistake. I've edited to correct that.

Answer (score 2):

Just use callback in replace.

```
regex.Replace(textContent, delegate(Match m) {
    int id = -1, newId;
    if (Int32.TryParse(m.Groups["RefId"].Value, out id)) {
        if (idDictionary.TryGetValue(id, out newId))
            return newId.ToString();
    }
    return m.Value; // if TryGetValue fails, return the match
});
```

Comment: If it doesn't match, you probably want to return `m.Value` by default (as the asker's code doesn't make a change in that case. If it *does* match... you need to return a string, not an int.

Comment: Well, it comes *closer* to compiling now, but it's not quite there yet.

Comment: Almost! (This is fun ^^)

Comment: @Rawling well, it might be for ya :) Can you be specific?

Comment: :) You've still got a branch with no `return` in it.

Comment: @Rawling okay. Now it's catch-all.

Comment: i extended your solution by adding a "left" and "right" group to the regular expression, and adding left and right to the result. This way the html tag is not removed

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are pulling the new IDs from the HTML aswell, I don't see why you can't just use a direct `String.Replace` here

```
var html = "Some text some text <a href = '##1234'> stuff stuff stuff <a href='##9999'> xxxx";
var mappings = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
{
    { "1234", "100025" },
    { "9999", "100026" },
    ...
};
foreach (var map in mappings) 
{
    html = html.Replace("##" + map.Key, "##" + map.Value);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KZQpQ9)

Comment: @Benji_9989 if you have to replace 1 million anchors then your website has much bigger problems...

Comment: just an example to say that your solution will always make a bigger foreach than his way to do..

Comment: @Benji_9989 my dictionary is an example based on what the OP has already stated in their question, they have the mappings already (it could be coming from a DB/file etc.). It's irrelevant, the point is how they then use that to replace the tags is what the question is about. FYI, the foreach doesn't change size at all, the dictionary grows.

Comment: Your foreach is based on the dictionary count. The OP way to do it is based on the matches count.

Comment: if there are ids in the rest of the test, outside of an <a href...>, then they would be replaced aswell. The RegEx is needed because only IDs withing a hyperlink should be replaced

Comment: @Benji_9989 and if that's important then it's easily adjustable to do that - the point of the example is to demonstrate `String.Replace` can be used instead of a Regex. Alexander Mills that's a bit of a moot point, just be more specific with your replace string `html.Replace("href='##" + map.Key + "'", "href='##" + map.Value + "'")`. It's a suggestion because generally `string.Replace` is *far* more efficient than `Regex.`. However, if you really need the pattern matching then there's no way around it.

Comment: I wanted to use RegEx since the HTML may contain tons of whitespace and still be valid. Without that problem, you would be right :-)

Comment: @AlexanderMills it's nice to know that thinking outside the box on this site gets you downvotes...

Comment: @James i did not downvote you and i appreciate your answer, like every other answer and comment

Comment: If thinking outside the box means make the first code working so yes... Your way to do it is far from a good solution, well it works... but see the difference with Rawling's solution in terms of performance with a big dictionary.

Comment: @Benji_9989 sorry but if we are talking about performance `string.Replace` 100% faster than `Regex.Replace` - don't take my word for it [Comparing RegEx.Replace, String.Replace and StringBuilder.Replace](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2008/04/02/comparing-regex-replace-string-replace-and-stringbuilder-replace-which-has-better-performance.aspx). Regardless, the question did not have a scope yet you seem to keep focusing on information that is not measurable (and therefore potentially irrelevant). In fact, every point you have made on my answer has been more or less irrelevant.

Comment: @AlexanderMills thank you for counter-acting, clearly Benji_9989's, nonsensical downvote.

Comment: @Benji_9989 in what way am I blinded by my code? Do you even bother to read things or do you just see what you want to see? The facts are there for all too see, I'm not saying that my answer is the way to go I am simply pointing out that given the *facts* from the original question `Regex.Replace` appeared to be unnecessary when a `string.Replace` could clearly do the job. It would appear that your the one who is blinded, by their own ignorance.